# ASP.NET MVC - Getting QueryString values

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Under ASP.NET MVC are you supposed to pick up QueryString params the same way you do in ASP.NET WebForms? or does the `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]` declaration get used somehow?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Query string parameters can be accepted simply by using an argument on the action - i.e.

```
public ActionResult Foo(string someValue, int someOtherValue) {...}
```

which will accept a query like `.../someroute?someValue=abc&someOtherValue=123`

Other than that, you can look at the request directly for more control.

Comment: Will this prevent Query string attacks? like any script injection?

Comment: What's "someroute" in this case?

Answer (score 44):

I think what you are looking for is

```
Request.QueryString["QueryStringName"]
```

and you can access it on views by adding `@`

now look at my example,,, I generated a Url with QueryString

```
 var listURL = '@Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Sector", action = "List" , name = Request.QueryString["name"]})';
```

the listURL  value is `/Sector/List?name=value'`

and when `queryString` is empty

listURL  value is `/Sector/List`

Answer (score 26):

You can always use `Request.QueryString` collection like Web forms, but you can also make MVC handle them and pass them as parameters. This is the suggested way as it's easier and it will validate input data type automatically.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using the ValueProvider property of the controller, much in the way that UpdateModel/TryUpdateModel do to extract the route, query, and form parameters required.  This will keep your method signatures from potentially growing very large and being subject to frequent change.  It also makes it a little easier to test since you can supply a ValueProvider to the controller during unit tests.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can capture Query strings in MVC in two ways.....

```
public ActionResult CrazyMVC(string knownQuerystring)
{

  // This is the known query string captured by the Controller Action Method parameter above
  string myKnownQuerystring = knownQuerystring;

  // This is what I call the mysterious "unknown" query string
  // It is not known because the Controller isn't capturing it
  string myUnknownQuerystring = Request.QueryString["unknownQuerystring"];

  return Content(myKnownQuerystring + " - " + myUnknownQuerystring);

}
```

This would capture both query strings...for example:

```
/CrazyMVC?knownQuerystring=123&unknownQuerystring=456

Output: 123 - 456
```

Don't ask me why they designed it that way. Would make more sense if they threw out the whole Controller action system for individual query strings and just returned a captured dynamic list of all strings/encoded file objects for the URL by url-form-encoding so you can easily access them all in one call. Maybe someone here can demonstrate that if its possible?

Makes no sense to me how Controllers capture query strings, but it does mean you have more flexibility to capture query strings than they teach you out of the box. So pick your poison....both work fine.

Answer (score 2):

@Context.Request.Query["yourId"]

Comment: @Context.Request.QueryString["yourId"] to be exact https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way in .NET 6 (and other netcore)

var Param = Request.Query["IndexString"];

If need to be string

string Param = Request.Query["IndexString"].ToString();