# How do I get the route and query string values in a mvc view

Tags: model-view-controller, view

If I have this URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/question/ask?type=great
```

How do I get the complete route and query string values in the View most economically eg this

```
/question/ask?type=great
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get to it from the View, you could use httpcontext

like this:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the action method in your controller to automatically parse the query string for you.  You don't need to do anything to your route.

[get query string values in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627838/asp-net-mvc-getting-querystring-values)

Comment: public actionresult Ask(string type)