# URL parameters in MVC 4 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Let say I have two methods in MVC 4 Web API controller:

```
public IQueryable<A> Get() {}
```

And

```
public A Get(int id) {}
```

And the following route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default", 
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works as expected. Adding a one more parameter, e.g.:

```
public IQueryable<A> Get(int p) {}

public A Get(int id, int p) {}
```

leads to the situation when MVC returns 404 for the following request:

```
GET /controller?p=100
```

Or

```
GET /controller/1?p=100
```

with message "No action was found on the controller 'controller' that matches the request"

I expect that URL parameters should be wired by MVC without issues, but it is not true. Is this a bug or my misunderstanding of how MVC maps request to action?

Comment: [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774984.aspx/2/10) the same issue is described but with no conclusion is this behavior expected

Comment: PS. due to the same issue OData syntax in URL will not work if there are more than one method mapped to the HTTP Verb.

Comment: Can you show your actual route and the all methods and signatures in your controller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think about what you're attempting to do and the routes you're trying, you'll realize that the second parameter "p" in your case, needs to be marked as an optional parameter as well.

that is your route should be defined like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Default", 
routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{p}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, p = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Once you do this, the URL

/controller?p=100
will map to your

```
public IQueryable<A> Get(int p) {}
```

method and a URL like so:

```
 /controller/1?p=100
```

will map to your

```
public A Get(int id, int p) {}
```

method, as you expect.

So to answer your questions....no this is not a bug but as designed/expected.

Comment: This is OK, but as far as I remember when some time ago used MVC 2, the common way is just to specify method parameters, without touching the route. Example: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627838/asp-net-mvc-getting-querystring-values) - and MVC should carry out the job for wiring Query part of the URL to input parameters.

Comment: @pborovik, As I said, earlier, "if you think about it", you will realize that you need to specify that the second parameter is optional as well. You can't say the first parameter is optional but the second is not. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @pborovik if you defined "overloads" for these methods, then the API controller will dispatch to those methods in the case the second parameter is not provided. But in your case you have only the two methods, so the dispatcher can't dispatch to any action method.

Answer (score 0):

In the WebApiConfig add new defaults to the httproute

> RouteParameter.Optional for the additional routes did not work for me

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{voucher}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional ,defaultroute1="",defaultroute2=""}
        );
```