# How can I store value until users clicks to get this value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I´m developing Web Api Asp.Net so I made a service for recovery password like this:

**Service**

```
  public string RecoveryGuid(string usuario, UsuarioRecuperacion user)
        {
            var usr = _usuarioService.Cargar(x => x.Cuenta == usuario);
            var fechaExpiracion = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);


            user.UsuarioID = usr.ID;
            user.FechaExpiracion = fechaExpiracion;
            var token = user.Codigo = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            user.Activo = true;
            _dbset.Add(user);
            _contexto.SaveChanges();

            string page = "<a href ='" + GetBaseUrl() + "Cliente/#/cambiarContrasena.html?Token="+token+"'> Recovery Password</a>";

            _emailService.EnviarCorreo(usuario, "Recover your Password",
                           "clic to unlock your account" + page);

            return page;

        }
```

I 
As you can see I send an email to user applying with url `Cliente/#/cambiarContrasena.html` plus `?Token="token"`
Token variable is saved into my database in this table for recovery Password with UserId, so I have for example:

```
UserId = 20
Token = 04309d96-4257-4383-bbde-5712ec6aa9cb
```

But now I want to know how to retrieve this token when user clicks on email . In this case for example `http://localhost:557/Cliente/#/cambiarContrasena.html?Token=04309d96-4257-4383-bbde-5712ec6aa9cb`

What I need to do in my service to detect when user click link and get token into antoher service like:

```
public string CambiarContrasena()
        {
           var a= "";

//What I need to do there to get token

            return  a;
        }
```

Comment: You've stored it in the DB haven't you? Your method needs to accept a parameter, the token number. Then inside your method you go look that token up the database (i.e. using LINQ)

Comment: Yes, token is stored into my database, can you give me an example please? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: An example of how to add a parameter to your method or an example of how to get data out of a database? To be honest these things are just a google search away so I'd prefer not to unless you try it yourself. By all means post any issues after you try it. In your method `CambiarContrasena` I assume you don't want to get "a" token, you want to get "the" token that has just been passed in by the link.

Comment: I search in google but I think I´m not good because I don´t found any that I want.  @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: I know how to add parameter is as simple as: `public string CambiarContrasena(string token)`, but how can I say to method that string token equals to url user clic? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: That's the way MVC routing works. If you submit the correctly crafted URL, the parameter is automatically recognised. Your URL calls method `CambiarContrasena` with parameter `Token` (though I wouldn't expect the `.html` bit). I suggest you experiment - add your parameter to your method and it _should_ be automatically picked up. See the accpeted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627838/asp-net-mvc-getting-querystring-values. It should just work. Please put the parameter in and try it and post back any issues.