# How to pass data through an url to Controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass data from url to my Controller.
The url looks like that: 
http://localhost:5000/#/pages/recover?username=someusername

My view controller looks like that:

```
public class PagesController : Controller
{
     public IActionResult Recover(string username)
     {
           return View();
     }
}
```

I put a breakpoint on return statement, when the break point is hit, the username is null. What else do I need to add to get the username from the url?

Comment: [Should just work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627838/asp-net-mvc-getting-querystring-values/40284720). Show your actual controller code and query string. You probably have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Remove the `#`. This specifies a [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) that *may* identify a location inside a document. It's not used in routing. It has no meaning for the web server

Comment: @Panagiotis well spotted. That might mean there's a clientside app which reads the fragment, reorganizes the UI and issues a request. That actual request should probably be fixed.

Comment: If I remove the #, the url doesn't work.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't fully understand you, what do you mean by "That actual request"?

Comment: The request issued by your clientside app. `http://localhost:5000/#/pages/recover?username=someusername` won't end up in the controller you show, it ends up in an Angular app or whatever. Then that app issues a request to your controller. The problem lies with that request.

Comment: So you say, it's might be because I'm using the # in the url?